# Laravel localization does not support Arabic

Tags: php, laravel

I'm using Laravel 6 and trying to make a dual-language page but I faced a serious problem when dealing with Arabic script.

I installed mcamara package then created `test.blade.php` page for testing purposes which has the following code regardless of bootstrap and styling stuff:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"/>
        <body>
            <nav class="navbar navbar-expand-lg navbar-light bg-light">
            @foreach(LaravelLocalization::getSupportedLocales() as $localeCode => $properties)
            <a class="navbar-brand" href="{{ LaravelLocalization::getLocalizedURL($localeCode, null, [], true) }}">{{ $properties['native'] }}</a>
            @endforeach
            </nav>

        <h1>{{ __('messages.test') }}</h1>
        <h1>اختبار</h1>
    </body>
</html>
```

And these are my lang files named 'messages' in Arabic:

```
'test'=>'اختبار',
```

And in English:

```
 'test'=>'test',
```

Now the first `h1` tag contains the word that must be translated according to language switching, but instead of getting an understandable word I get these strange characters `Ø§Ø®ØªØ¨Ø§Ø±`, and when I wrote the Arabic 'اختبار' word -which means 'test'- as a string it showed up very well.

Here is my input: [enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/IZgtQ.png)

I'm using VS code and all my pages has UTF-8 encoding. I also tried to put this code: `Blade::setEchoFormat('e(utf8_encode(%s))');` in Boot class in AppServiceProvider.php but it does not work.

I hope I can find help.

Comment: You didn't close the header `<head><meta http-equiv="Content-Type" content="text/html" charset="utf-8"/></head>`

Comment: I close it but it didn't work

Answer (score 1):

Salam @Hani, it looks like an encoding problem.

I tried to reproduce your case in my local computer, I copy paste your code and everything works as expected.

Check to see if your files `messages.php` in `resources/lang` are in a correct encoding format.
If they are, check the blade file.

You can also try to make a test route that only returns the translated string like so :

```php
Route::get("test", function(){
    return __("messages.test");
});
```

Comment: It looks like I have an encoding problem. I will focus on fix it that way.

Answer (score 1):

It appears to be that your file is not correctly saved in UTF-8. You can see it yourself [here](https://www.branah.com/unicode-converter). Paste the text you see on the page (`Ø§Ø®ØªØ¨Ø§Ø±`) into `UTF-8 text (Example: a ä¸­ Ð¯)` text box then you will see that it is actually `اختبار` in Unicode.

To solve the problem, you need make sure that your files are saved in UTF-8.

[image: UTF-8 to Unicode conversion]

Comment: Yes, I got the same result. I will focus on making my pages be saved in UTF-8.